# Intersection problem: too many elements?

Tags: arcgis-server, c#, map-service, asp.net, arcgis-web-adf

I have this code where an IGeometry shape (4-5 circles not filled) should be intersected with another layer's features

```
                // Convert from IGeometry to ADF Geometry Polygon
                ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPointCollection com_pointcollection =
                        (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPointCollection)multipointPoints2;
                ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.Geometry.Point[] new_adf_points =
                                        ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.DataSources.ArcGISServer.Local.Converter.FromIPointCollection
                    (com_pointcollection);
                ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.Geometry.PointCollection new_adf_pointcollection = new
                    ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.Geometry.PointCollection();
                for (int i = 0; i < new_adf_points.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    new_adf_pointcollection.Add(new_adf_points[i]);
                }

                ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.Geometry.Ring new_adf_path = new
                    ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.Geometry.Ring();
                new_adf_path.Points = new_adf_pointcollection;
                ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.Geometry.RingCollection new_adf_pathcollection = new
                    ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.Geometry.RingCollection();
                new_adf_pathcollection.Add(new_adf_path);
                ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.Geometry.Polygon new_adf_polygon = new
                    ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.Geometry.Polygon();
                new_adf_polygon.Rings = new_adf_pathcollection;



                // Now get the intersect query

                ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.SpatialFilter spatialFilter =
                    new ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.SpatialFilter();
                spatialFilter.Geometry = new_adf_polygon;
                spatialFilter.ReturnADFGeometries = false;
                spatialFilter.MaxRecords = 10000;

                System.Data.DataSet queryResultsDataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
                for (int index = 0; index < layerIDs.Length; index++)
                {
                    System.Data.DataTable queryResultsDataTable =
                  queryFunctionality.Query(queryFunctionalityq.Name, ConvertFromLayerNameToLayerId(m_Map, m_ResourceMapItem, m_firstLayerName), spatialFilter);
                    queryResultsDataTable.TableName = gisResource.Name + "_" + layerNames[index];
                    queryResultsDataSet.Tables.Add(queryResultsDataTable);
                }
```

I'm converting the IGeometry (which I've drawn on the screen and I know it's correct) to a web ADF Polygon and then using this polygon for an intersection query

However some features which are clearly not intersecting the circles' borders are being included in the result

To better explain the situation I did this screenshot:

[image]

Why is that? The red squared features are all different so it's not a problem of "same feature"

Update: with less features it's the same, if they intersect the circle line they get colored, but the others get colored too.. simply adding them seems like telling the system "I'm intersected too"

Comment: How does this question differ from your preceeding one at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13456/intersection-failing-because-of-vertices-of-polygons?

Comment: Totally, the problem is different and I've solved the one before.

Comment: I asked the question because it is not clear how the two questions are different.  Both appear to be the same problem with intersecting two layers.  The figure is confusing because it's not clear what layer is what.  What role, for instance, do the green quadrilaterals play?  What is the difference between red and cyan squares--does red denote selection or something else?

Comment: Let's see: I'm trying to intersect two layers, the green regular squares constitute the first layer and the unfilled circles are the second layer. I'm trying to color red ONLY the squares which intersect with the circles but I'm failing because as you can see other squares are being colored (also if they do not intersect the circles). So red is selected. Do not consider the cyan non-square figures because they play no role in here.

Comment: Thanks, Paul.  The example is sufficiently irregular that it doesn't reveal much about the nature of the error, only that there is an error.  Why don't you simplify things?  A good start would be to intersect a regular grid of squares with a single circle.  If that works, add more circles until you get a failure.  Often, the process of simplifying an error instance leads to either a better characterization of the problem or even to a solution.

Comment: very weird, with less features it's the same, if they intersect the circle line they get colored, but the others get colored too.. simply adding them seems like telling the system "I'm intersected too".

I'm planning to use the ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ISpatialFilter (just to see if the error is the same) but I'm getting server context errors on this line

ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IMapServer iMapServer = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IMapServer)ctx.ServerObject;

Comment: It's ok to edit your original question, Paul, to reflect the additional information you're gathering.  When you can strip a problem down to its essence with a simple example and an account of what's happened, it's more likely someone will identify a solution.